# The right way to construct HTTP request to API in Nodejs and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I'm totally new to HTTP and trying to make HTTP request. Here is the API:

[image]

I construct the request like this:

```
let reqString = 'GET https://login.yandex.ru/info?format=json&with_openid_identity=1 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
          'Authorization: OAuth ' + this.token;
```

And here is the error:

```
Error: Invalid URI "GET%20https://login.yandex.ru/info?format=json&with_openid_identity=1%20HTTP/1.1%0D%0AAuthorization:%20OAuth%20AQAAAAAc3LKEAAQQaS1B6d6nz0B8mq_kOr-AD6M"
```

I'm totally new to HTTP and backend at all, please, explain what I'm doing wrong and show me the right way

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, this function takes a URL, not a request.

Comment: Remove `GET` from URL?

Comment: not quite sure how that one single line of code could cause the error - perhaps you could try to show what you are **really** doing

Comment: @guest271314 - and remove `HTTP/1.1\r\n`, and set the header as a header, not as part of the request .... and ... well, there's probably more wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX, please tell me, how to set the header as a header

Comment: @CommercialSuicide - do it the usual way like on line 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my case was to create the object and make HTTP request like this:

```
const request = require('request');

let reqobj = {
        uri: 'https://login.yandex.ru/info?format=json&with_openid_identity=1 HTTP/1.1',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + this.token
        }
      };

request(reqobj, (error, response, body) => {...}
```

Thanks for help in comments